# How to complete request before redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

Using C#/Asp.Net

I have an application that goes out to a web service. On return there's a couple of things that happen:

```
    void Cleanup(Response response)
    {
          // My web service takes up to 30 seconds 
          // then this method is called

          // I send this email
          var email = SaleEmail.Create(
            response.ID
            DateTime.Now,
            "A sale was made!");

        email.Send();

        // Then redirect
        Response.Redirect(response.RedirectUrl, false);
        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

The idea is, on completion of the web service an email is sent, then the page is redirected.

Previously, I used a normal redirect - the result was that 90% of the emails were never sent.

I've changed the redirect pattern, however it's still not perfect - I'm guessing 25% of emails are still not coming through.

Anyone advise any improvements to the pattern I have?

Email code:

```
        public static void Send(MailMessage message)
        {
            Guard.Argument.NotNull(() => message);

            var c = new SmtpClient();

            try
            {
                c.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                c.Dispose();
                message.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you used smtpClient ?

Comment: I'm using WebClient but that's not the issue - if I remove the redirect everything works fine. I used to display a splash screen and let the user redirect themselves but that is no longer possible.

Comment: i'm talking about sending mail using smtpClient ?

Comment: What happens in `email.Send();`

Comment: @PranavPatel - sorry misunderstood - the email code is now posted above

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - email code now posted

Answer (score 2):

Maybe 
Try to implement **async task method** with **sendAsync and await**
this await will help you to wait how much needed to send email before jump to redirect

```
//async Task
public async Task Cleanup(Response response)
{
     using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        await smtpClient.SendAsync();...//await
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - unfortunately the site is currently running ASP.Net 4 so I can't use async

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266277/how-do-i-call-async-methods-in-asp-net-c-sharp-4-0

Comment: Look here you still able to reach that await but just in different way

Answer (score 0):

you should rewrite your initialization somehow, make it look like this:

```
smtpClient.SendAsync();
smtpClient.SendCompleted  += new SendCompletedEventHandler(smtpClient_SendCompleted);
```

on `smtpClient_SendCompleted` function write your redirection code